# If there is in a category $\mathcal{A}$ finite products and equalizers then it has pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, abstract-algebra

My homework consist in showing that "If there is in a category $\mathcal{A}$ finite coproducts and coequalizers then it has pushouts" based on the proof that "If there is in a category $\mathcal{A}$ finite products and equalizers then it has pullbacks" .This  last proof was given in class but somehow is lost in my notes, and I'm looking for it. If anyone of you can sketch it or give me any hint I'll be glad. Thank you in advance

Comment: Moderators can export comments, and I can do so for you, but you should open an account there. But a hint for your problem is to see the pullback of two maps $f: A \to C$ and $g: B \to C$ as a subobject $e = \langle p_1, p_2 \rangle: P \to A \times B$ where $e$ is an equalizer of two maps $A \times B \to C$ where the relevant equation expresses the commutativity of the pullback diagram. But this is a very good exercise for you to do on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Construct the pullback $A \times_C B$ as the equalizer of two morphisms $A \times B \to C$ (suitably defined). If you have no idea, recall the construction of pullbacks in $\mathsf{Set}$. The general case works *verbatim*.